# On which intervals is the following function increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

$f: \mathbb{R_{+}} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^a-a^x$ ( $a$ is a positive constant).

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=ax^{a-1}-\ln{(a)}a^x$$

we need to solve

$$ax^{a-1}-\ln{(a)}a^x>0$$

which would define a $2D$ region where for a given value of $a$ would give the interval that satisfies above (the cross section at $a=c$ for constant $c$ in the graph) . Note for $a<0$ the solution is complex and for $a=0$ it is undefined. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+ax%5E%7Ba-1%7D-%5Cln%7B%28a%29%7Da%5Ex%3E0+) gives you a free snippet of the $2D$ region.